# Listview - itemchecked

Tags: vb.net, listview

I need help with using the ListView.ItemChecked event.
In a new procedure (triggered by the ItemChecked event), I need to extract a data from the record that is checked.

This is the code (to complete) that doesn't work:

```
Private Sub lvDetail_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles lvDetail.ItemChecked
    If e.Item.Checked Then
        MsgBox("Selected: " & e.Item.SubItems(4).Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Deselected: " & e.Item.SubItems(4).Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

The lvDetail.ItemChecked event appears to run the test I wrote for each line when adding all the records within the lvDetail control.

To populate the listview object, I need to use the Add statement in a loop:

```
For Each ws_film In ws_elenco_film
Dim item As New ListViewItem(ws_film.Get_Titolo)

item.SubItems.Add(ws_film.Get_Id_tmdb)

lvFilmDetail.Items.Add(item)
Next

lvFilmDetail.EndUpdate()
```

When I populate the listview the event procedure is executed for all records...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks Semola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's no way around the event being raised. I just tested setting `CheckBoxes` to `False` before adding the items and that prevented the event being raised when the items were added but setting `CheckBoxes` to `True` again caused the event to be raised for each item.

I'd suggest that you're best option is to use a flag of your own that you can test in the event handler.  It won't stop the event being raised but you don;t actually have to do anything when it is.  e.g.

```
Private Sub lvDetail_ItemChecked(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles lvDetail.ItemChecked
    If Not ignoredItemChecked Then
        If e.Item.Checked Then
            MsgBox("Selected: " & e.Item.SubItems(4).Text)
        Else
            MsgBox("Deselected: " & e.Item.SubItems(4).Text)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and

```
ignoreItemChecked = True

For Each ws_film In ws_elenco_film
    Dim item As New ListViewItem(ws_film.Get_Titolo)

    item.SubItems.Add(ws_film.Get_Id_tmdb)

    lvFilmDetail.Items.Add(item)
Next

ignoreItemChecked = False
```

The alternative would be to not use a `Handles` clause but instead register the event handler using `AddHandler` and not do so until it was already populated.